# How can I detect if all images are loaded in document?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing a firefox extension and need to know that all images are loaded without attaching onload event handler to those images. Is this possible?

I tried `document.images[0].complete` attribute but it always returns true.

Comment: What's the reason you can't add handlers to the `OnLoad` event?

Comment: If I handle events for onload event, I will need to continuously check and compare the total number of images and fired onload events. But the other way i would know that not all of the images are loaded by checking images[0].complete return (true or false) in a loop, simple.

Comment: I agree; but you'll need an 'expected' count anyway, and the OnLoad approach means that you won't need to continually loop, you'll just attach them all to the same handler, and check when the currentCount == expectedCount.

Comment: try workaround `!!document.images[0].width`

Answer (score 1):

```
function allImagesLoaded() {
    for(var i = document.images.length - 1; i>= 0; --i) if(!document.images[i].complete) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In firefox, complete always returns true